# Is it possible to find the parent of an element then navigate the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When using jQuery how does one return to navigating the DOM. For example, if I found the parent of an item like this:

```
$(this).parent()
```

How can you find something with an id of 'foobar'.
I've tried:

```
$(this).parent().$('foobar').addClass('hello')
```

But I get the message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method '$'
```

Answer (score 1):

IDs must be unique, for selecting an element by ID you can use ID selector `$('#foobar')`, however  if you want to find an element within the parent element you can use `find` method:

```
$(this).parent().find('#foobar').addClass('hello');
```

Which is the same as:

```
$('#foobar').addClass('hello');
```

Note that if you are using an ID for several elements, your document is invalid, you should use classes instead.

```
$(this).parent().find('.foobar').addClass('hello');
```

Comment: Or just $('#foobar').addClass('hello');

Comment: In this case either the answer or first comment would work. In general with jQuery, you have to go back first, stop, then search. So the above goes back to the parent, then stops and uses the find method to search from there.

Comment: Both work but for an 'id' there is no point working in reference to anything else. If you were using a 'class' then find('.classname') would be the better option (providing the element is contained within the parent, obviously).

Answer (score 0):

while id should be unique, so that you can just `document.getElementById("foobar")` I have had to find multiple occurrences before and used this:

```
/* returns an array of all elements with id */
function getElementsById(id){
  var t=document.getElementsByTagName("*"),a=[]
  for(var i=0;i<t.length;i++)
    if(t[i].id==id)a[a.length]=t[i]
  return a
}
```

Note: if you are writing new code, classes have a builtin getElementsByClassName (because it is expected to have multiples)

Edit: this could be reduced to `document.querySelectorAll("#id")`